# C# condition adjustment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this condition here:

```
<td>$@(inventory.Elevations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == e)?.Price.ToString("N0") ?? "Not Available")</td>
```

This works very well but if x.Title is not equal to e the dollar sign at the beginning is still appearing, I only want the dollar sign to appear if x.Title is equal to e...how would I adjust this so the dollar sign only appears with the Price and not with "Not Available"

Comment: Check the [currency formatting in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-currency-c-format-specifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below method,

```
<td>@(inventory.Elevations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == e)?.Price.ToString("C0") ?? "Not Available")</td>
```

C0 - this will change the string to currency format.

I hope this  helps.